# Android: delay before show checked checkbox

Tags: android-recyclerview, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, android-checkbox, android-mvvm

I will start with the example:

- One list with a checkbox for each row
- a data model
- a ui data model

the click on the checkbox modifies the list data model and its liveData.
Who observes the liveData see the change and transforms it into the uiModel then give it to the list adapter and this using the diffUtil updates the list punctually.
All this is "slow", a 2 or 4 hundredths of a second before show the checkbox checked.
When I check the checkbox I have to validate the new dataModel, for instance: in some case I have to show some alert, or to disable some rows.

How do you deal with this type of "issue"?